# How to override keyPressEvent of QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtextedit

I override keyPressEven() of widget QTextEdit:

```
void myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key()==Qt::Key_0)
    {
        qDebug() << "Ok";
    }
}
```

Button 0 works - show "Ok", but does not write in field of QTextEdit. Why? Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the base class implementation if you want to keep the default behaviour:

```
void myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key()==Qt::Key_0)
    {
        qDebug() << "Ok";
    }
    QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
}
```

See the docs for [keyPressEvent](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone using `PySide2` is having trouble overriding `QTextEdit`'s built-in keybindings, I post my solution here. Hopefully this is also useful for C++.

---

### Scenario:

We are using a `QTextEdit` in an application and want to distribute a series of keybindings, but the text editor has already several hardcoded bindings. We want the editor to ignore them **and** hand them over to its parent, so they can be eventually handled by our code.

### Problem:

While the docs say that whenever an event is ignored (e.g. by returning `True` in the installed `eventFilter` method) it automatically gets passed on to the parent, the truth is that when doing that for predefined keybindings **`QTextEdit` did not hand them over: the event got ignored AND absorbed**. So any textedit built-in keybindings filtered this way will be effectively globally disabled.

Direct event passing via `sendEvent` inside the editor's `eventFilter` had an interesting effect:

- When calling `sendEvent` and returning `super().sendEvent`, the keybinding got executed by the editor AND the event passed to the receiver.
- When calling `sendEvent` and returning `True`, the keybinding didn't get executed, and the event didn't get passed to the receiver.
- When calling `sendEvent` and returning `False`, the keybinding didn't get executed, and the event passed to the receiver **twice**.

Furthermore:

- Using `event.ignore()` didn't have any effect: the editor executed the built-in anyway.
- Trying to discriminate via `event.spontaneous()` caused a segfault due to a missing pointer. Probably something got GCed but didn't try to debug that.
- Trying to replace the event with a "dummy event" and call super also didn't work. Magically, the text editor kept executing the built-ins.

Maybe I missed something. Anyway, below I detail the approach that worked for me.

---

### Solution:

The plan is to completely block the event, but broadcast it via `signals`, and then connect to them wherever we want. In your text editor instance, define the signal e.g. as follows:

```py
eventCatched = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QEvent)
```

Then, e.g. the following event filter will prevent execution of a few keybindings, and emit them once via `eventCatched`:

```py
def eventFilter(self, obj, evt):
    """
    Remember to install via self.installEventFilter(self)
    """
    catch_control_keys = {QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, QtCore.Qt.Key_Right}
    catch = False
    # documentation for keys and modifiers:
    # https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html
    if evt.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        modifiers = evt.modifiers()
        ctrl = bool(modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier)
        shift = bool(modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier)
        alt = bool(modifiers & QtCore.Qt.AltModifier)
        key = evt.key()
        # catch all undo/redo builtins
        if ((ctrl and shift and key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z) or
            evt.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo) or
            evt.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Redo)):
            catch = True
        # catch specified control-keys
        if ctrl and not shift and not alt:
            if key in catch_control_keys:
                catch = True
    #
    if catch:
        # block event but send it as signal
        self.eventCatched.emit(evt)
        return True
    else:
        return super().eventFilter(obj, evt)
```

Then, we are free to connect the signal wherever we want to, we just need a method that handles events. In my case, I just wanted to pass them to the main window, which can be done with the following one-liner in the constructor:

```
text_editor.eventCatched.connect(lambda evt: QtCore.QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self, evt))
```

---

This way, whenever we catch an event in the text editor, it will be ignored and won't be propagated the standard way. Instead, a signal will be emitted, and we can subscribe to that signal to e.g. restart the propagation tree at a different point, as shown here via `sendEvent`.

Hope this helps!
Cheers,
Andres